# How to navigate between pages/controllers in SharePoint Application

Tags: client-object-model

I am using MVC to create SharePoint Provider Hosted App. How to create navigation menu in Share Point Application, for example if i just create hyperlink it doesn't take SPHostUrl and other query string parameters to next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not seeing how you insert the hyperlink, but in MVC you need to set the needed querystring variables explicitly for a hyperlink. One thing you might do is persist the SPHostUrl into a session or cookie variable, and use that value as a source for the SharePoint token for each next request after the first one, when you do not want to put it on the querystring for each request.